# Simple Android app

Tags: android

Where I can find simple open source Android app with 4-5 inherited activities and using threads? For my use only. Maybe a little game with poor graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here from below link you can understand basic of game development in android

http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Look through the google API demoes, downloadable from the android sdk manager in eclipse